# Read information about a directory and it's sub-directories using python

Tags: python, django, glob

I'm working on a python(3.6) project in which I need to clone a GitHub repo which will have the directory structure as:

```
|parent_DIR
|--sub_DIR
   |file1....   
   |file2....
|--sub_DIR2
   |file1...
```

Now I need to get the following info:

```
1. Parent directory name
2. How many subdirectories are
3. names of subdirectories
```

Here's how I'm cloning the GitHub repo:

**from views.py:**

```
# clone the github repo
tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
saved_unmask = os.umask(0o077)
out_dir = os.path.join(tempdir)
Repo.clone_from(data['repo_url'], out_dir)
```

Answer (score 0):

To iterate through the directory, use `os.scandir(path='parent_directory')`. This returns iterator of `os.DirEntry` objects, one for each file or directory in the parent directory. `dir_entry.name` will give you the file/subdirectory name,  and the object can tell you if the entry is a directory or not with `is_dir()`. For each subdirectory, call the same function again, and so on for each sub-directory of the sub-directory (if that exists).

To get the number of directories & files in a directory, increment a counter for each object the iterator return you (keep in mind this will include `.` and `..`)

Comment: `for entry in os.scandir('path'):  counter += 1  name = entry.name`

Answer (score 0):

Possibly, you could use os.walk(dir) (a code sample below).

```
import os
import tempfile


tempdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
saved_unmask = os.umask(0o077)
out_dir = os.path.join(tempdir)

# Create a few dirs.
os.makedirs(out_dir + "/parent_DIR")
os.makedirs(out_dir + "/parent_DIR/sub_DIR")
os.makedirs(out_dir + "/parent_DIR/sub_DIR2")
os.makedirs(out_dir + "/parent_DIR/sub_DIR3")
os.makedirs(out_dir + "/parent_DIR/sub_DIR3/subsub_DIR")

i = 0
for _, subdir_list, _ in os.walk(out_dir):
    if i == 0:
        parent_dir_name = subdir_list[0]
    else:
        break  # Do not go deeper.
    i += 1

print("The parent dir name is: %s" % parent_dir_name)
print("The number of subdirs is: %s" % len(subdir_list))
print("The list of subdirs is: %s" % subdir_list)
```

My output of the sample:

```
The parent dir name is: parent_DIR
The number of subdirs is: 3
The list of subdirs is: ['sub_DIR3', 'sub_DIR', 'sub_DIR2']
```